# Using custom buttons with js & php

Tags: php, dhtml, javascript

How can I make a form with my own "submit" button & post the info to a php server side?

how can I get js to post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `submit()` method to submit forms via javascript:

```
document.form_name.submit();
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('form_id').submit();
```

Or:

```
document.forms[0].submit(); // submit first form on page
document.forms[1].submit(); // submit second form on page
```

If you don't want to use a `submit` button and want to use a normal button, you just need to put any of the above code in `onclick` event of that button.

Comment: Thanks, the second worked.

the first didn't... I got error on the page. By "form_name" do you mean it's ID or the "name" attribute?

Comment: @Gal Miller: It meant name of the form :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id=myForm action=process.php>

<input name=text>

<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/submit.gif">

</form>
```

To submit

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```